# (google-play-music-desktop-player:8454): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:34:57.633: cannot open display: :0

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, snapcraft

I use Ubuntu 18.04.
I've installed https://snapcraft.io/google-play-music-desktop-player
When I run it, there is the error in syslog:

```
(google-play-music-desktop-player:8454): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:34:57.633: cannot open display: :0
```

Other snap applications work without any problem, does anybody know how to fix the problem?

**Update:**
Looks like it's a bug. I reported the issue to GitHub https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player-UNOFFICIAL-/issues/3738

Comment: looks like this should be a bug report, not a stackoverflow question

Comment: @knocte thanks for your reply, I reported gh issue. I hoped for fast workaround, but didn't find it.

Comment: if you reported it, edit your question to add a link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed after reporting the github issue
https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player-UNOFFICIAL-/issues/3738#issuecomment-571833703